# How to install vpnbook under kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to install free vpn under my kubuntu 22.04

From the site I uploaded a file vpnbook-openvpn-us1.zip and unpacking it I got 4 files :

```
vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn
vpnbook-us1-udp25000.ovpn
vpnbook-us1-udp53.ovpn
```

I tried to run command but got error :

```
sudo vpnbook vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
  
[sudo] password for master: 
sudo: vpnbook: command not found
```

I did not find "vpnbook" comand in my OS or under synaptic.
I find some youtube video manual...

Where from have I to get vpnbook command to install free vpn?

Comment: ovpn files are OpenVPN configuration files. Try: https://tecadmin.net/install-openvpn-client-on-ubuntu/